# TYPO3 6.2 - how to create FileReference in frontend (FE)?

Tags: file-upload, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x, fal

I have the hypothetical `Zoo` extension in which I've `Animal` model with `photo` field and FrontEnd (FE) plugin with typical CRUD actions. `photo` field is typical FAL's `FileReference` and it works perfectly in backend (BE) with common TCA IRRE config.

I'm able to  successful upload the file to the storage, it's visible in the **Filelist** module, and I can use it in BE during my Animal editing, anyway I can't create `FileReference` within my FE plugin.

My current approach looks like this:

```
/**
 * @param \Zoo\Zoo\Domain\Model\Animal $animal
 */
public function updateAction(\Zoo\Zoo\Domain\Model\Animal $animal) {

    // It reads proper uploaded `photo` from form's $_FILES
    $file = $this->getFromFILES('tx_zoo_animal', 'photo');

    if ($file && is_array($file) && $file['error'] == 0) {

        /** @type  $storageRepository \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\StorageRepository */
        $storageRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\StorageRepository');
        $storage = $storageRepository->findByUid(5); // TODO: make target storage configurable

        // This adds uploaded file to the storage perfectly
        $fileObject = $storage->addFile($file['tmp_name'], $storage->getRootLevelFolder(), $file['name']);

        // Here I stuck... below line doesn't work (throws Exception no. 1 :/)
        // It's 'cause $fileObject is type of FileInterface and FileReference is required
        $animal->addPhoto($fileObject);

    }

    $this->animalRepository->update($animal);
    $this->redirect('list');
}
```

anyway attempt to create reference by this line throws exception:

```
$animal->addPhoto($fileObject);
```

How can I resolve this?

Checked: `DataHandler` approach ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25054980/1066240)) won't work also, as it's unavailable for FE users.

**TL;DR**

How to add `FileReference` to `Animal` model from existing (just created) FAL record?

Comment: Did you check http://insight.helhum.io/post/85015526410/file-upload-using-extbase-and-fal-in-typo3-6-2 - it is a different approach than  your code in `uploadAction` as it uses a generic typeconverter to convert your uploaded file (or files) to an object which is directly used when creating your `Animal` model. Works perfectly both in FE and BE.

Comment: @derhansen thx, that's first thing you see when googling, TBH, I was hope there's simpler solution for such a ... basic thing, anyway as I can see I need to dig deeper into Helmut's poc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to do several things. This [issue on forge](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/48965) is where I got the info, and some stuff is taken out of [Helmut Hummels frontend upload example](https://github.com/helhum/upload_example) (and the [accompanying blogpost](http://insight.helhum.io/post/85015526410/file-upload-using-extbase-and-fal-in-typo3-6-2)) which @derhansen already commented.

I'm not entirely sure if this is everything you need, so feel free to add things. This does not use a TypeConverter, which you should probably do. That would open further possibilities, for example it would be easily possible to implement deletion and replacement of file references.

You need to:

- Create a FAL file reference object from the File object. This can be done using FALs resource factory.
- Wrap it in a `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference` (method `->setOriginalResource`)
- **EDIT:** This step is unnecessary as of TYPO3 6.2.11 and 7.2, you can directly use the class `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference`.

  But, because the extbase model misses a field (`$uidLocal`) in 6.2.10rc1, that won't work. You need to inherit from the extbase model, add that field, and fill it. Don't forget to add a mapping in TypoScript to map your own model  to `sys_file_reference`.

  ```
  config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes.Zoo\Zoo\Domain\Model\FileReference.mapping.tableName = sys_file_reference
  ```

  The class would look like this (taken from the forge issue):

  ```
   class FileReference extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference {

       /**
        * We need this property so that the Extbase persistence can properly persist the object
        *
        * @var integer
        */
        protected $uidLocal;

        /**
         * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceInterface $originalResource
         */
        public function setOriginalResource(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceInterface $originalResource) {
            $this->originalResource = $originalResource;
            $this->uidLocal = (int)$originalResource->getUid();
        }
    }
  ```
- Add this to the TCA of the image field, in the config-section (adapt to your table and field names of course):

  ```
  'foreign_match_fields' => array(
      'fieldname' => 'photo',
      'tablenames' => 'tx_zoo_domain_model_animal',
      'table_local' => 'sys_file',
  ),
  ```
- **EDIT**: Use `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference` in this step if on TYPO3 6.2.11 or 7.2 or above.

  So at the end add the created `$fileRef` instead of `$fileObject`

  ```
  $fileRef = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('\Zoo\Zoo\Domain\Model\FileReference');
  $fileRef->setOriginalResource($fileObject);

  $animal->addPhoto($fileRef);
  ```
- Don't tell anyone what you have done.

Comment: Jost, ok, I won't tell anybody ;) Finally I realized that I totally missed TypeConverters in the past.

Comment: #biesior your question and #Jost your answer save my day. I have followed all steps, create new file FileRefence.php under my model. Everything is working after remove typo3temp ;) also I have to change my set method in model. Thank you both of you Gentleman :)

Comment: Actually it saved my day again yesterday ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete function to upload file in TYPO3 using FAL and create filereference

```
/**
 * Function to upload file and create file reference
 *
 * @var array $fileData
 * @var mixed $obj foreing model object
 *
 * @return void
 */
private function uploadAndCreateFileReference($fileData, $obj) {
    $storageUid = 2;
    $resourceFactory = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory::getInstance();

    //Adding file to storage
    $storage = $resourceFactory->getStorageObject($storageUid);
    if (!is_object($storage)) {
        $storage = $resourceFactory->getDefaultStorage();
    }

    $file = $storage->addFile(
          $fileData['tmp_name'],
          $storage->getRootLevelFolder(),
          $fileData['name']
    );


    //Creating file reference
    $newId = uniqid('NEW_');
    $data = [];
    $data['sys_file_reference'][$newId] = [
        'table_local' => 'sys_file',
        'uid_local' => $file->getUid(),
        'tablenames' => 'tx_imageupload_domain_model_upload', //foreign table name
        'uid_foreign' => $obj->getUid(),
        'fieldname' => 'image', //field name of foreign table
        'pid' => $obj->getPid(),
    ];
    $data['tx_imageupload_domain_model_upload'][$obj->getUid()] = [
        'image' => $newId,
    ];

    $dataHandler = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
        'TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler'
    );
    $dataHandler->start($data, []);
}
```

> **where** $filedata =
>   $this->request->getArgument('file_input_field_name');

And

> $obj = //Object of your model for which you are creating file
>   reference

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I get the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function writelog() on null in /var/www/typo3_src-7.6.15/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/DataHandler.php on line 8138` and found following issue on TYPO3 forge: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/75805. Am I doing something wrong, or why is this working for you and not for me? :-)

Answer (score 0):

This example does not deserve a beauty prize but it might help you. It works in 7.6.x

```
private function uploadLogo(){

   $file['name']    = $_FILES['logo']['name'];
   $file['type']    = $_FILES['logo']['type'];
   $file['tmp_name']  = $_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'];
   $file['size']    = $_FILES['logo']['size'];

   // Store the image
   $resourceFactory = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory::getInstance();
   $storage = $resourceFactory->getDefaultStorage();

   $saveFolder = $storage->getFolder('logo-companies/');
   $newFile = $storage->addFile(
     $file['tmp_name'],
     $saveFolder,
     $file['name']
   );

   // remove earlier refereces
   $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_DELETEquery('sys_file_reference', 'uid_foreign = '. $this->getCurrentUserCompanyID());

   $addressRecord = $this->getUserCompanyAddressRecord();

   // Create new reference
   $data = array(
     'table_local' => 'sys_file',
     'uid_local' => $newFile->getUid(),
     'tablenames' => 'tt_address',
     'uid_foreign' => $addressRecord['uid'],
     'fieldname' => 'image',
     'pid' => $addressRecord['pid']
   );

   $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_INSERTquery('sys_file_reference', $data);
   $newId = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_insert_id();

   $where = "tt_address.uid = ".$addressRecord['uid'];
   $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_UPDATEquery('tt_address', $where, array('image' => $newId ));
}
```